# How can I loop through the first 'n' rows in a grid view.

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a question about if there is a better more efficient way to do what I want to accomplish:

What I want to do is loop through the rows in a grid view and check the check boxes for the first 100 records.

For this I came up with the solution below:

```
int limit = 0;
int max = 100;
foreach (GridViewRow gvr in GridView1.Rows)
{
    limit++;
    if (gvr.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && limit <= max)
    {
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)gvr.FindControl("chkSelect");
        cb.Checked = true;
    }
}
```

I am wondering if this is the best way of doing this or if there is an easier/quicker way to do accomplish the same task.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you use a for-each loop if you dont want to check all rows? I would use a normal for loop like so:

```
int max = 100;
for (int i = 0; (i < GridView1.Rows.Count && i < max); i++)
{
    GridViewRow gvr = GridView1.Rows[i];
    if(gvr.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow){
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)gvr.FindControl("chkSelect");
        cb.Checked = true;
    }
}
```

The check `i < GridView1.Rows.Count` is optional, but prevent you from outofbounds exceptions.

Comment: The foreach goes through all the gridview rows even if thelimit is already met.  I think using a simple for loo is mch better. Thanks. Not sure why someone downvoted my question.. oh well ;p Thanks for ur help.